# Magento: What directories and files can I safely delete?

Tags: magento

I have a 2 year old install of Magento 1.4.0.1 with 500MB gzipped. I use an [image cleaning extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/image-clean.html) to remove unused product images. I know I can clear `var`. But Magento produces a lot of caches, thumbnails, downloaded extensions, etc.

What other directories can I safely clear to reduce a tar backup size, that if I needed to use that backup and that backup alone, everything would work normally? (db is backed up separately) For example, can I clear `downloader`? Anything in `media`? Any tips to save space is appreciated.

Comment: You can delete anything in `media/catalog/product/cache/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we use GIT, we have a .gitignore file. These are all files that I can stand to loose and will not miss.

- var/* (I'd leave the empty directories there though.)
- media/catalog/product/cache/*
- media/js/*
- media/css/*.css

Oh, and leave the downloads directory. There's a record kept there of what's been installed.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Excluding media/catalog/product/cache/* reduced my backup by 250MB! If I find any others we can exclude, I'll report back here.

Comment: You can also ignore `media/css_secure`

Answer (score 2):

`media/tmp/catalog/product/*` is also safe to delete.

Comment: Why not just `media/tmp`? Do you know if it is safe to ignore from here onwards?

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer won't help OP.
Apart from above mentioned folders,
You can also exclude:

- `/includes/src/*`

These are compiler generated files and are safe to remove.